# Getting 401 Unauthorized with jmeter when moving test plan to a new machine

Tags: jmeter, macos-high-sierra

I am using Jmeter on Mac OSX and for some reason the same script which runs successfully on a windows based pc ends up not running on mac.

When looking at the server log, i get a 401 error, even though jmeter GUI shows everything ran fine.

Not sure how best to even describe the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Are you testing a REST or a SOAP WS? Are you sending a simple HTTP Request? 401 is a security error. The server rejected your request. Maybe because you didn't provide any credentials? Are you using Basic Auth? Try to be more specific please.

Comment: I am sorry but i barely know anything about Jmeter. So was so non descriptive in my question. Will upload more info shortly.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all make sure to have the same JMeter version ([preferably latest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)) on both machines.
2. Second check *jmeter.log* file - it normally contains enough troubleshooting information to get to the bottom of the issue or guess where the problem lives
3. If you use external data files in i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) make sure to use forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes `/` in paths.

   ```
   testdata/testfile.csv
   ```
4. In addition to point 3 make sure to copy all the related data files or .jmx scripts or whatever
5. If your test relies on any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - make sure to install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), it will automatically detect missing components and suggest to download them

Going forward try to provide more information, i.e. screenshot of your test plan, server log file, [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener output for request and response for problematic sampler, jmeter.log file, etc.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the Jmeter version. With version 5 the scripts do not seem to work. Had to download version 4 and run the script. Will update and upload more info to resolve the issue that scripts can run on version 5 as well.